# Invalid CSRF token found - Spring Boot and Axios

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, csrf

I would like to post using `Axios` to my `Spring Boot` server. If I disable `csrf` using `.csrf().disable()` it works correctly however it fails when enabled.

I've tried adding `X-CSRF-TOKEN` to the header, or `_csrf` in the body but it is saying it is invalid. Checking the request the `csrf` is being passed in as expected.

**CSRF Controller**

```
@RequestMapping("/csrf")
public String csrf(final CsrfToken token) {
    return token.getToken();
}
```

**Spring Security**

```
httpSecurity
        .antMatcher("/api/**")
        .cors().and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
```

**Axios**

```
axios
    .post(
      `/api/doSomething`,
      { id: id, _csrf: csrf},
      {
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': csrf
        }
      }
    )
    .then(response => {
      resolve(response.data);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      reject(error);
    });
```

**MetaTags `react-meta-tags` store the CSRF**

```
<MetaTags>
  <meta name="csrf-token" content={csrfToken} />
</MetaTags>
```

**Axios to get the CSRF token**

```
axios
.get('/csrf', {
  withCredentials: true
})
.then(response => {
  resolve(response.data);
})
.catch(error => {
  reject(error);
});
```

**Function to get the CSRF token from the meta tags**

```
function getCSRFFromPage(): string | null {
  const element = document.querySelector("meta[name='csrf-token']");

  if (element !== null) {
    const csrf: string | null = element.getAttribute('content');
    return csrf;
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
Invalid CSRF token found for <url>
```

What could be causing this to fail?

Comment: Can you show the JavaScript code you use to retrieve the CSRF token? (e.g. where does the `csrf` variable in the axios  call come from).

Comment: @g00glen00b I've updated the question. I retrieve the CSRF token using a get. I then store it in the meta tags and I get the value when posting to axios and add it to the header.

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible causes.

First of all, the CSRF token endpoint should match the Spring Security configuration. In your example, you're using `antMatcher("/api/**")`, but CSRF token endpoint is `/csrf`. This should likely become `/api/csrf`.

The second part is that the CSRF token changes after each request. You didn't show the code where you invoke `getCSRFFromPage()`, but this should happen before each call you make. If not, then only the first call with that CSRF token will succeed. All consecutive calls will fail.

If you don't like making an additional call with each request, then you can use the `CookieCsrfTokenRepository`:

```java
httpSecurity
    // ...
    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
```

By doing so, each time you make a request, you'll get an `XSRF-TOKEN` cookie containing the next CSRF token. This should be passed within the `X-CSRF-TOKEN`  or `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header. Many libraries, including Axios do this out of the box, so you don't have to do anything else.

You can customize this behavior by configuring the `xsrfHeaderName` or `xsrfCookieName` properties (see [Request Config](https://github.com/axios/axios#request-config)).

Comment: This looks like a step closer. I've set the token repository like you've mentioned. Now I no longer need to call my `csrf` endpoint and it is automatically adding the `XSRF-TOKEN` request header to my axios post like you mentioned. After this I'm still getting the Invalid CSRF token error. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Michael Can you try doing a single GET before doing any POST call? My guess is that you didn't receive the cookie yet containing a proper CSRF token,so maybe you're relying on a CSRF token cookie from earlier.